# SQL 'IS NOT NULL' fails to filter rows and return an emtpy set

Tags: sql, mariadb

Obviously the title is provocative, but this is where I'm stuck.

I have an SQL query with a JOIN that returns a single row (even though the result set is empty) because of the count(r.sid) function on the column 'sid' of the joint table. I wanted to filter it out checking that the primary key c.cid is not NULL but I get a non empty set anyway....(removing count(r.sid) makes the query return an empty set as expected)

```
MariaDB [***]> select count(r.sid),c.code,c.created,c.cid from conference as c left join registrations as r on r.cid=c.cid where c.code = 'not_existing_code' and c.code is NOT NULL;
```

```
+--------------+------+---------+-----+
| count(r.sid) | code | created | cid |
+--------------+------+---------+-----+
|            0 | NULL | NULL    | NULL|
+--------------+------+---------+-----+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

-- M

Comment: Why is the result empty? A result wit a `count(...)` is at least a single row.

Comment: Your `GROUP BY ( )` operation is over that one group containing 0 rows.  If you want to filter groups, use a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Don't forget that your SELECT list contains expressions not functionally dependent on the GROUP BY terms.  That will also be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. This is interesting to me, my SQL knowledge is actually rather naive and I didn't think of the GROUP BY introduced by count() and its implications.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select COUNT(r.sid)  ,c.code,c.created,c.cid
from conference as c 
left join registrations as r on r.cid=c.cid 
where c.code = 'not_existing_code' 
and c.code is NOT NULL
Group by c.code,c.created,c.cid
Having COUNT(case when r.sid IS NOT NULL THEN r.sid END)>=0
```